# Mysql Error Code: 1147 REVOKE ALL privileges ON amanidb.users FROM agent@192.168.0.65

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

when trying to revoke user i get this error.

```
GRANT ALL privileges ON amanidb.* to agent@192.168.0.65;


REVOKE ALL privileges ON amanidb.users FROM agent@192.168.0.65;
```

i get this message :

```
  REVOKE ALL privileges ON amanidb.users FROM agent@192.168.0.65    Error Code: 1147. There is no such grant defined for user 'agent' on host '192.168.0.65' on table 'users'   0.016 sec
```

Comment: The error is plain English. What don't you understand?

Comment: What do you see if you do `show grants for agent@192.168.0.65`?

Comment: 00:42:50 show grants for agent@192.168.0.35 Error Code: 1141. There is no such grant defined for user 'agent' on host '192.168.0.35' 0.000 sec

Comment: `35` should be `65` like in your question.

Comment: If you grant permissions on `amanidb.*` you can't revoke on specific tables, you can only revoke on `amanidb.*`

Comment: i get this 'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `agent`@`192.168.0.65`'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `amanidb`.* TO `agent`@`192.168.0.65`'

Comment: barmar i want revoke only a specifc table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233821/discussion-between-bigtheo-and-barmar).